# Git remote push not working, SSH key issues

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, git-remote

I have an Amazon EC2 webserver that I'm trying to push to.  Its SSH connections are authenticated with a key with no password.  I have set up my local machine's ssh config file like so

```
Host web                                                                        
Hostname <path to host>                                                           
User ubuntu                                                                     
IdentityFile <path to key>                                   
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and when I do

```
ssh web
```

I log in just fine, but when I try to do

```
git push web
```

I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

on the local macine and

```
Connection closed by <local machine's IP> [preauth]
```

In the ssh auth.log file on the server.  I've been over and over the SSH and git files on both the server and local, and I just can't get it.  What could I be missing?

.git config on local is

```
[core]                                                                          
    repositoryformatversion = 0                                             
    filemode = true                                                         
    bare = false                                                            
    logallrefupdates = true                                                 
[remote "origin"]                                                               
    url = https://<bitbucketpath>.git    
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                             
[branch "master"]                                                               
    remote = origin                                                         
    merge = refs/heads/master                                                 
[remote "web"]                                                                  
    url = ubuntu@<server ip>:/home/ubuntu/git/test.git                  
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/web/*
```

the repo is owned by ubuntu, which is the user that would be logging in via ssh as specified in the config.

Comment: Your url starts with `https://`, but you're looking into ssh authentication.  I'm guessing you want `ssh://`.

Comment: That's for origin, I'm talking about the web remote.

Unless that matters?

Comment: Oh, yes, I see.  I'd be explicit (ssh://user@addr/home/...) but it should be defaulting to ssh there, yes (hence should not matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ssh configuration block begins with `Host web`. When you test this with ssh, you run the command `ssh web`. SSH looks up the entry for "web" in the ssh config file and uses those parameters.

However, in git your remote is

```
[remote "web"]                                                                  
    url = ubuntu@<server ip>:/home/ubuntu/git/test.git                  
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/web/*
```

Here, you are not using a hostname, you're using an IP address. You need to update your ssh config so it knows to use the desired parameters for this IP address, not only for the hostname "web". Just add the IP to your `Host` entry.

```
Host web 1.2.3.4
```

(Obviously, substitute the real IP address in place of `1.2.3.4`.)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it!  Strange that the tutorials I've seen didn't mention this.  Thanks!